# Add a column (dependent upon another) every th

Tags: r

My `data.frame(Analysis)` consists of the following:
`Person <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)`
`Score <- c(10, 12, 11, 15)`
`Sample <- c(1, 2, 3, 4`)
`Person.1 <- c(2, 2, 2, 2)`
`Score.1 <- c( 20, 18, 23, 24)`
`Sample.1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)`
I wish to include a new column `(Analysis$Time)` that divides each entry in `Analysis$Sample` by 100, per `Person`, but am unsure how to do so? I have attempted:
`Analysis$Time <- with(Analysis, Sample/100)`
Although this code just inserts a column at the end of `Analysis` and not for each `Person`.The sample rate of my measure is 100 Hz. The expected output would be:
`Person <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)`
`Score <- c(10, 12, 11, 15)`
`Sample <- c(1, 2, 3, 4`)
`Time <- c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04)`
`Person.1 <- c(2, 2, 2, 2)`
`Score.1 <- c( 20, 18, 23, 24)`
`Sample.1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)`
`Time.1 <- c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04)`
I am not concerned by the column headers of `Analysis` as I merge the columns for further analysis via the code below, hence the need to have a `Analysis$Time` column for each `Person`.
`StatsOutput <-  data.frame(Person=unlist(Analysis[grep('^Person', names(Analysis))]), 
                     Score=unlist(Analysis[grep('^Score', names(Analysis))]),
                     Sample=unlist(Analysis[grep('^Sample', names(Analysis))]), 
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
row.names(StatsOutput) <- NULL`

Comment: Did you round the value for `Time` in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
ind <- grep('^Sample', names(Analysis))
nm1 <-  make.unique(rep('Time', length(ind)))

Analysis[nm1] <- Analysis[ind]/100
Analysis1 <- Analysis[order(sub('[^.]+', '', names(Analysis)))]
```